# Get numbers only from a text file using c

Tags: c, arrays, file

**/edited/**
I'm new here.
I have a text file that reads:

```
6
<cr>
R 0
R 1
R 4
R 36
R 0
R 4
```

This is what I have. I want to read each line into an array so that I can convert that array into an integer so I can print only the numbers of whichever line I want later.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main()
    {
        FILE *fr;   /*declares file pointer*/
        int i, j, num[32];
        char array[32][32], input_file[32], line[32];
        printf("Enter file: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", input_file);    
        fr = fopen(input_file, "r");
        for(i=0;i<32;i++)
            for(j=0;j<32;j++){
                array[i][j] = \'0';
            }
            for(i=0;i<32;i++){
                line[i] = '\0';
            }
        if(fr != NULL){

            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fr) != NULL){
                strcpy(array[i],line);
                    num[i] = atoi(array[i]);
                        i++;
                        printf("%d\n", num[i]);
            }
        }fclose(fr);
        else{
            perror(input_file);
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors but it isn't printing the right thing; this is what it prints:

```
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
```

Can anyone explain to me what is going wrong?

Comment: I don't see where `array` is declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I'd handle this a bit differently. Though you haven't stated it explicitly, I'm going to assume that the first number is telling us how many more lines of letters/numbers we're going to read (not including the blank line). So, we want to read that, then read the rest of the lines, ignoring any leading non-digits, paying attention only to the numbers.

If that's correct, we can simplify the code somewhat:

```
int num_lines;
int i;
int *numbers;

fscanf(infile, "%d", &num_lines); // read the number of lines.

numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_lines); // allocate storage for that many numbers.

// read that many numbers.
for (i=0; i<num_lines; i++)
    fscanf(infile, "%*[^0123456789]%d", numbers+i);
    // the "%*[^0123456789]" ignores leading non-digits. The %d converts a number.
```

Comment: I got an error saying "assignment of pointer struct_iobuf to pointer to char".....it didn't like the scanf line. I substituted "fr" for you "infile".

Comment: Excellent! I would also check the return value of scanf in case there are lines without numbers on them.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin  So after this, are the numbers stored to "numbers"? How do I get them so I can print them out? Sorry this is all a new concept to me.

Comment: @oldbutnew: Yes, you can treat `numbers` like an array, so you can print them out something like: `for (i=0; i<num_lines; i++) printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);` When you're done using them, you want to free the memory with: `free(numbers);`

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks so much for your help Jerry! I have been working at this for a few days. And I'm pretty sure I tried printing numbers[i] last night just like this. I think the compiler I'm using is a little faulty. Which one do you use?

Comment: @oldbutnew: It's *rarely* the compiler's fault. I currently mostly use MS VC++, but also keep gcc/g++ and Comeau handy. At times I've also used Intel, Borland, etc. Although I could point to bugs in all of them, all of them are more than good enough for most routine coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

1. You're never setting `input_file` to anything, so you seem to be opening a random file.
2. You're double-using `i` in the nested loops.
3. You're not showing `array` at all, so it's impossible to tell how it's declared.
4. You are increasing the loop index *before* using it to print the number, so you're always "missing" and printing the number in the next (not yet written) slot.

You should use `memset()` to clear the arrays if you're worried. There's no need to clear arrays that are going to be overwritten, such as `line` which is written to by `fgets()`.

Comment: I added the parts I left off.

Comment: so should I just move the print in front of the index increment, or do I need to increase the index outside of the while loop?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `array` is a `char` array, when you do:

```
...
strcpy(array[i],line);
num[i] = atoi(array[i]);
...
```

Your actually converting the entire line and not the `integer` in it. You should consider using `fscanf`, or at least search for the integer inside the line variable and convert it.

Doing `atoi(array[i])` is the same as `atoi("R 32\n")` for example.